# Instaling multi-node kubernetes cluster on windows

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, vagrant, minikube

I have worked with minikube as a single node Kubernetes cluster on windows to learn it. Now, I need to figure if it is possible to create a multi-node Kubernetes cluster on windows using other Vms..

I need to figure also the best production scenario for windows( to automate the Vms creation, configuration ), as alternative like (vagrant / ansible) on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Feel free to create several VMs manually in the tool of your choice and network them together.

Vagrant and Ansible (Pull) work fine on Windows as well, where Ansible runs in the guest OS.

Or you can run Ansible and/or Docker from WSL.

FWIW, other than for learning purposes, there is little benefit of simulating a cluster of Kubernetes/Openshift or similar platform on all single machine. The same resources should work whether you have one node or many

Comment: Personally, I use a [Nomad cluster](https://medium.com/hashicorp-engineering/hashicorp-nomad-from-zero-to-wow-1615345aa539), not kubernetes at home for development

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I will try it.